# QComboBox, part of simple QDialog, wrapped in a QGraphicsProxyWidget, does not respond to mouse wheel events

Tags: qt, pyqt, qgraphicsscene, qcombobox

I have a simple `QDialog`, containing only a `QComboBox` and a `QPlainTextEdit`, contained by a `QGraphicsProxyWidget`. Usually, a focused `QComboBox` responds to `wheelEvent`s, changing its `currentIndex`. However, in this `QGraphicsProxyWidget`, there is no response whatsoever.

As an experiment, I've also tried catching the `wheelEvent`, either in `QComboBox`, or in the `QGraphicsProxyWidget`, but it too is never called.

How can I get the embedded `QComboBox` to respond to mouse wheel events? First prize if you know how to have it responding to mouse events when the popup list is shown.

Comment: Does it work when the mouse is directly over the `QComboBox`?

Comment: It doesn't work when it's directly over. It also doesn't work if I first actually click on it to make it pop out, and also not if I make the popup go away by selecting an item or by pressing escape. (and thank you very much for the edits!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was working, the path with which the event would be propagated is:

`QGraphicsView::wheelEvent`

`QGraphicsScene::wheelEvent`

`QGraphicsWidget::sceneEvent` (the proxy widget's parent class)

`QGraphicsItem::sceneEvent`(the proxy widget's parent's parent)

`QGraphicsProxyWidget::wheelEvent`

`QComboBox::wheelEvent`

You already know it's not getting as far as `QGraphicsProxyWidget::wheelEvent`, so if I were you I would go further up the chain to find where it's getting stuck.

Are you overriding wheelEvent anywhere else, like in QGraphicsView or QGraphicsScene? If so, that's probably the source of your problem, since these classes are supposed to forward events to their children.

Comment: Genius! I forgot to look in my derived QGraphicsView, thanks. I have a wheelEvent there, but it's calling event.ignore() in this specific case (I double-checked), and still my combobox is not getting it. However, when I completely disabled my QGraphicsView.wheelEvent the problematic QComboBox started working! So the ignore() is somehow not working. Any more ideas?

Comment: Instead of calling e.ignore, I'm calling the parent wheelEvent() and now everything is working. Thanks again for applying your deductive powers to my problem!

Comment: Yep, that's what I would have suggested if I had seen your reply in time. :)  Glad I could help.